# what is the use of parentheses in linux command

Tags: linux, terminal, ubuntu-server

I run following command in Linux terminal. Can anyone tell me what is the use of parentheses in Linux terminal and following command also ?

**$(echo "GET / HTTP/1.0";echo "Host: www.google.com"; echo) | nc www.google.com 80**

Answer (score 1):

`( list )`
Placing a list of commands between parentheses causes a subshell environment to be created, and each of the commands in list to be executed in that subshell. Since the list is executed in a subshell, variable assignments do not remain in effect after the subshell completes.

Comment: Also, any other environment changes, such as a `cd` command, are localized to the context of the subshell, and disappear when the subshell is exited.

Answer (score 1):

Parentheses denote a subshell in bash. In your command, the $() is command substitution and if it is like () is a subshell. Both of them run commands, the difference is what happens to the output.

[Unix & Linux Answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26063/how-are-parentheses-interpreted-at-the-command-line)